# Extract the sum of two things from datatable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

I have a table in a SQL Server database with many columns but the important columns are `LoggedState` and `InteractionType`.

I need to find the number of break agents and the number of idle agents.

#### What I have tried

```
SqlCommand GraphCmd = new SqlCommand("getAgentStatues", Graphsqlcon);
SqlParameter tdate = new SqlParameter();
GraphCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; ;
SqlDataAdapter DAGraph = new SqlDataAdapter(GraphCmd);
DataSet DSGraph = new DataSet();
DSGraph.Clear();
DAGraph.Fill(DSGraph);
DataTable DTgraph = new DataTable();
DTgraph = DSGraph.Tables[0];

int numberOfBreakAgents = 0;
int numberOfIdelAgents = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in DTgraph.Rows)
{
     String LoggedState = row["LoggedState"].ToString().Trim().ToLower();
     String InteractionType = row["InteractionType"].ToString();
     if (LoggedState == "break")
     {
          numberOfBreakAgents++;
     }
     else if ((LoggedState == "activo") && (row["InteractionType"] == DBNull.Value))
     {
          numberOfIdelAgents++;
     }
}
```

it works perfectly, but I am asking if there is a way (like grouping) to avoid the `foreach` statement

Comment: It may be none of my business, but you seem to have an extra semicolon on line 3 that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Group` function from Linq:

```
var loggedStateGroups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(d => d["LoggedState"].ToString(), (group, row) => new
{
    LoggedState = group,
    AllCount = row.Count(),
    NullCount = row.Where(r => r["InteractionType"] == DBNull.Value).Count()
});
```

That will group by the LoggedState with a count for each matching row (`AllCount`) and a count for rows where the InteractionType is `DBNull.Value` (`NullCount`).

We can then select the counts we are after by doing:

```
int numberOfBreakAgents = loggedStateGroups.Where(y => y.LoggedState == "break").First().AllCount;
int numberOfIdelAgents = loggedStateGroups.Where(y => y.LoggedState == "activo").First().NullCount;
```

Note I'm only using `First` assuming you will always have results. If you won't always have results you should use `FirstOrDefault` and perform a null check.

You could filter before using the `Group` by adding the following `Where` depending on your data.

```
.Where(r => r["LoggedState"].ToString() == "break" || r["LoggedState"].ToString() == "activo")
```

I've tested this with the following setup:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("LoggedState");
dt.Columns.Add("InteractionType");

dt.Rows.Add("break", "inter1");
dt.Rows.Add("activo", DBNull.Value);
dt.Rows.Add("break", "inter1");
dt.Rows.Add("break", "inter2");
dt.Rows.Add("activo", "inter2");
```

And I get `3` and `1` for the `numberOfBreakAgents` and `numberOfIdelAgents` respectively.

**Edit for using FirstOrDefault:**

If you'd like to perform the null check as mentioned above you can replace the two `int` declaration lines above with:

```
var breakAgents = loggedStateGroups.Where(y => y.LoggedState == "break").FirstOrDefault();
var idelAgents = loggedStateGroups.Where(y => y.LoggedState == "activo").FirstOrDefault();

int numberOfBreakAgents = breakAgents != null ? breakAgents.AllCount : 0;
int numberOfIdelAgents = idelAgents != null ? idelAgents.NullCount : 0;
```

This is taking the first group that has the LoggedState of "break" or `null` if there isn't one. It then assigns `numberOfBreakAgents` the `AllCount` property if the group is not null or `0` if it is.

A similar thing is done for `numberOfIdelAgents` except we filter for the "activo" group and use the `NullCount` property as we aren't interested in *all* rows we are only interested in those where the InteractionType was `DBNull.Value` which we've captured in the `NullCount` property.

The null check is necessary if the result set will ever contain zero rows with the LoggedState of "activo" or zero rows with the LoggedState of "break". In that instance the `.First()` will return `null` and accessing `AllCount` or `NullCount` from that will result in a "Sequence contains no elements" exception.

Using the following DataTable definition will highlight the difference as it causes an exception for `numberOfBreakAgents` using `First()` but correctly returns `0` when using `FirstOrDefault`.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("LoggedState");
dt.Columns.Add("InteractionType");

dt.Rows.Add("activo", "inter1");
dt.Rows.Add("activo", DBNull.Value);
dt.Rows.Add("activo", "inter1");
dt.Rows.Add("activo", "inter2");
dt.Rows.Add("activo", "inter2");
```

Comment: could you update your answer and use first or default pleae? +1

Comment: when you used First of default, you removed the checking of null in the `activo` condition. that is very important to me

Comment: I think that there is no need for first of default, because now the result is empty though your code gives me zero and that is good

Comment: I don't think I did. The null check on `activo` is in the join which populates the `NullCount` property of the group. In my `FirstOrDefault` code I'm checking if there are any _LoggedStates_ that match "activo" and if there are I take the _NullCount_ (the number of rows where the  and not the _AllCount_ like I do for the "break" group.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I've updated the answer again to add some more clarification. I think you probably do need the null check but I don't know enough about your data to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not do

```
var breakAgents = from row in DTgraph.AsEnumerable()
where row["LoggedState"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "break"
select row;
var breakAgentsCount = breakAgents.Count();
```

and

```
var idleAgents = from row in DTgraph.AsEnumerable()
where row["LoggedState"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "activo"
&& row["InteractionType"] == DBNull.Value
select row;
var idleAgentsCount = idleAgents.Count();
```

Comment: in your first line, there is no `Where` in `Rows`

Comment: Changed to make DTgraph an IEumerable<DataRow>

Comment: after `DBNull.Value` you have `)`. Why is that `)` ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake - taken it out.

Comment: +1 for the efforts. I didn't find the write answer yet because my teammate removes some data.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Count-function that LINQ provides us, the following solution should work:

```
// Cast the rows to a collection of DataRows.
IEnumerable<DataRow> collection = DTgraph.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();

// Get the number of Break Agents.
int numberOfBreakAgents = collection.Count(row => row["LoggedState"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "break");
// Get the number of Idel Agents.
int numberOfIdelAgents = collection.Count(row => row["LoggedState"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "activo" && row["InteractionType"] == DBNull.Value);
```

The cast is used to allow the use of LINQ on the DataRow-collection.

---

Another option would be to cast the DataRow-collection to a List of type DataRow. Then using a ForEach (also LINQ), to determine the agent-type:

```
List<DataRow> collection = DTgraph.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();

collection.ForEach(row =>
{
    if (row["LoggedState"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "break")
        numberOfBreakAgents++;
    else if (row["LoggedState"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "activo" && row["InteractionType"] == DBNull.Value)
        numberOfIdelAgents++;
});
```

Above example is very much the same to your example, but written a bit shorter and without the use of two strings (LoggedState and InteractionType).

Comment: i tried your first way and I keep getting zero zero, though I can see the results have values

Comment: Can you check if the collection gets filled? So after the cast that is.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute sql query like this:

```
select 
   sum(case when LoggedState = "break" then 1 else 0 end) break_count,
   sum(case when LoggedState = "activo" and InteractionType is null then 1 else 0 end) active_count
from table_name
```

Comment: I don't have the table, I just have the stored procedure.

Comment: This query do what you need, you can use it inside stored procedure

Comment: i can just use the stored procedure, i am working on group and I don't have many permission